# Update current file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm creating code wherein Outlook will extract all emails to an existing Excel file.

The code works and extracts all emails from a selected folder. However, when I try to use the same code on a separate folder, let's say Sent Items, it doesn't extract the data and opens a Read only version of the Excel file.

I plan to leave Outlook and Excel Open.

How can I work with any Outlook folder and still update the Excel file?

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailv7()

Dim objNS As NameSpace
Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
Dim Selection As Selection
Dim obj As Object

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objItems As Outlook.Items

Dim myItem As MailItem

Dim myXLApp As Excel.Application
Dim myXLWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim StrBody As String
Dim TotalRows As Long, i As Long

Set objOL = Outlook.Application
Set objFolder = objOL.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set objItems = objFolder.Items

Set myXLApp = New Excel.Application
myXLApp.Visible = True
Set myXLWB = myXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Folder Name\SR Historyv2.xlsx")

Set excWks = myXLWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

TotalRows = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
i = TotalRows + 1

For Each obj In objItems

    If obj.Class = olMail Then
        'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
        excWks.Cells(i, 1) = Format(obj.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        excWks.Cells(i, 2) = obj.SenderEmailAddress
        excWks.Cells(i, 3) = obj.Subject

        i = i + 1

        'myXLWB.Save

    End If   
Next

Set obj = Nothing
Set objItems = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and if you would like to run Outlook Rule, let me know I will update the answer

```
Option Explicit
Sub Excel()
    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel App
    Dim xlWB As Object 'WorkBook
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim rngCount As Long
    Dim xlStarted As Boolean
    Dim xlPath As String
    Dim olExplorer As Explorer
    Dim olSelection As Selection
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olMsg As Object
    Dim xlColA, xlColB, xlColC, xlColD As String

    '// Path of the Workbook - update only -> "\Folder Name\Folder Name\Book1.xlsx"
    xlPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & _
        "\Documents\Temp\Book1.xlsx"

    '// Set up Excel Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlStarted = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    '// Open the workbook to input the data
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1") ' or use (1) or (Sheet Name)

    '// Record msg        
    On Error Resume Next
    '// Find the next empty line of the worksheet
    rngCount = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row


    '// Get the values from Outlook
    Set olExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer

    '// Select Outlook msg
    Set olSelection = olExplorer.Selection
    For Each olMsg In olSelection
        Set olItem = olMsg
        '// Info to collect
        xlColA = olItem.ReceivedTime
        xlColB = olItem.SenderName
        xlColC = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
        xlColD = olItem.To

        '// Write it to Excel sheet
        xlSheet.Range("A" & rngCount) = xlColA
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rngCount) = xlColB
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rngCount) = xlColC
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rngCount) = xlColD

        '// Go to Next row
        rngCount = rngCount + 1
    Next

    '// Save & Close Excel.Application
    xlWB.Close 1
    If xlStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

    '// Clean up
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set olMsg = Nothing
    Set olExplorer = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this one. I saw this code online and got bits and pieces of some of the code. However, I did not use this to run the script via rule. Appreciate the assistance..

Comment: @Wilson update xlPath workbook to yours- look at the comment in the code

Comment: i tried copying your code and tried running it and works like a charm! Thanks for this one. However, the Excel filename was closed BUT the Excel application was left open. The reason why I want the Excel filename to be left open is another incoming email will reference to this filename and see if it existing or not. If it is existing then it will show something -value, string etc. Is this possible or I really need to close the Excel file and have it opened again for the matching of the other incoming email? Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: noted this one and appreciate the assistance. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you close the SR Historyv2 workbook after you run the script or do you want to keep it open the entire time? If you keep it open and run the script again it will open the workbook a second time and that will be read only. For the second question i would suggest you look into the ItemAdd event in Outlook. This will only work if Outlook is open. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171270(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there no workaround for this one? Or it this how things really work (sorry VBA newbie here). I'm just afraid that if an incoming email comes in at the exact time, will the macro be able to extract both emails at the same time, or will it be one after the other? Or worse, the other email will not be extracted? For the second question, I managed to create an outlook rule wherein once a message comes in, it will run the script. Thanks for the suggestion-however which do you think would be better? To create the ItemAdd event or just create the rule?

Answer (score 0):

I got this code working properly

```
Set myXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
'specify the History File
With myXLApp
.Workbooks("SR Historyv2.xlsx").Activate
End With
```

It keeps the file to open and lets the other macro access it without being read-only.